# Azure Build Pipelines publish multiple webapps in same solution

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines

I am new to Azure Build Pipelines.

I've seen many posts and videos about how to create a simple pipeline using the Azure Devops UI (no YAML), with one Web Application project, but I have 2 applications, an asp.net Core Web Application (WebUI) and an asp.net Core Web API. For some reason, the artifact published from my build pipeline is only containing the WEBUI. I would expect that both projects be published as Artifacts.

Any suggestion on what I should do to have both artifacts as results from my build pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found my issue. I had a checkbox in the Publish Task called "Publish Web projects".

Once I unchecked it, both my artifacts were created.

[image]

Comment: Hi CidaoPapito, Thanks for sharing your findings and posting it here, you could Accept it as an Answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues, we appreciate your contribution to forum.